# Размещение элементов управления в Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Делаю простенькую программу с GUI:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объекты Entry и Button, стоящие рядом, должны находиться ниже на три ячейки. Как это сделать? Вот сам код:

```
from tkinter import *

class Shell(Frame):

def __init__(self, window):
    super().__init__(window)
    self.grid()
    self.__clicked = 0
    self.__init_widgets()

def __init_widgets(self):
    self.__lbl = Label(self, text = "Button clicked: " + str(self.__clicked))
    self.__lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    self.__btn = Button(self, text = "Click on me", command = self.__clicker)
    self.__btn.grid(row = 0, column = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    self.__ent = Entry(self)
    self.__ent.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    self.__ent_button = Button(self, text = "Enter", command = self.__input_bold)
    self.__ent_button.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = W)

    self.__fuck_label = Label(self, text = "Hey, bitch")
    self.__fuck_label.grid(row = 5, columnspan = 3)

def __clicker(self):
    self.__clicked += 1
    self.__lbl["text"] = "Button clicked: " + str(self.__clicked)

def __input_bold(self):
    if self.__ent.get() == "Fuck you":
        self.__fuck_label["text"] = "O_0"
    else:
        self.__fuck_label["text"] = "What a fuck did you say?!"


if __name__ == "__main__":

main_window = Tk()

main_window.title("Clicker")
main_window.geometry("200x200")

shell = Shell(main_window)

main_window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобыо отобразить пустые строки, можно воспользоваться методом `grid_rowconfigure`.

Вот простой пример:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

label1 = Label(root, text="Label 1")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

label2 = Label(root, text="Label 2")
label2.grid(row=3, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Если в примере закомментировать строку `root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)`, то пустых строк не будет.